# How to split double quotation from string in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have problem with inserting text from txt file into SQl Compact edition database.

the line in text file is like bellow:

```
item_code,Loc,cost_price,run_spr,recd_dt,disp_flag,R_qty,s_qty,a_qty,stk_qty,O_qty,
"017245588","I01","0.000","0.000","261013","N","0.000000","-2.000000","0.000000","-2.000000","0.000000"
```

it has 11 field

when I using this insert statement bellow:

```
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\SKORPIO\pdt_item.txt")
Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
While Not (sr.EndOfStream)
    line = sr.ReadLine()

    Dim fields() As String = line.Split(",")

    sqlstr = "INSERT INTO pdt_item (item_code,loc,cost_price,run_spr,recd_dt,disp_flag,R_qty,s_qty,a_qty,stk_qty,O_qty) VALUES( '" & fields(0) & "' ,'" & fields(1) & "','" & fields(2) & "','" & fields(3) & "','" & fields(4) & "','" & fields(5) & "','" & fields(6) & "','" & fields(7) & "','" & fields(8) & "','" & fields(9) & "','" & fields(10) & "' )"
    Dim obj As SqlCeCommand = New SqlCeCommand(sqlstr, conn)
    obj.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

the insert statement been like this

```
INSERT INTO pdt_item (item_code,loc,cost_price,run_spr,recd_dt,disp_flag,R_qty,s_qty,a_qty,stk_qty,O_qty) VALUES( '"017245588"' ,'"I01"','"0.000"','"0.000"','"261013"','"N"','"0.000000"','"-2.000000"','"0.000000"','"-2.000000"','"0.000000"' )
```

so because of two double quotations its give error

note that i did test manually without double quotations like in statement bellow its working normally.

```
INSERT INTO pdt_item (item_code,loc,cost_price,run_spr,recd_dt,disp_flag,R_qty,s_qty,a_qty,stk_qty,O_qty) VALUES( '017245588' ,'I01','0.000','0.000','261013','N','0.000000','-2.000000','0.000000','-2.000000','0.000000' )
```

So please how I can write code in VB to do this

Comment: What about a parameterized query?

Comment: Do you want to insert the quotes in your datatable or not?

Comment: No I dont want to insert quotes to my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct approach to this operations is through a parameterized query.
The matter is further complicated from the presence of double quotes around the field values that, I suppose, need to be removed before storing the value in the database

However, this could be the correct code....

```
   Dim fields() As String = line.Split(",")

   sqlstr = "INSERT INTO pdt_item " & _
   "(item_code,loc,cost_price,run_spr,recd_dt,disp_flag," & _
   "R_qty,s_qty,a_qty,stk_qty,O_qty) VALUES " & _ 
   "( @p1, @p2, @o3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11)"

   Dim obj As SqlCeCommand = New SqlCeCommand(sqlstr, conn)
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", fields(0).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", fields(1).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", fields(2).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", fields(3).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", fields(4).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", fields(5).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", fields(6).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", fields(7).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", fields(8).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", fields(9).Trim(""""c))
   obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", fields(10).Trim(""""c))
   obj.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

There is still a problem related to the datatype of the columns in the datatable. This code assumes that every column is of type text and so every parameter value is passed as a string. If this is not the case a conversion (and a check if the value could be effectively converted) is needed when adding the parameter value.

**EDIT** Looking at your comment below it is clear that the simple split operation is not enough to handle correctly the file data. You need to use an instance of a [TextFieldParser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It has a property named: `HasFieldEnclosedInQuotes` that, when set to true, allows to ignore the field separator (the comma) when it appears inside the double quotes

So your loop could be replaced by: (Warning NOT TESTED)

```
Using sr As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\SKORPIO\pdt_item.txt")
    sr.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    sr.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    sr.HasFieldEnclosedInQuotes = True
    Dim fields As String() = sr.ReadFields()
    While Not sr.EndOfData
        fields = sr.ReadFields()
        ......
```

Comment: Actually now the problem with the some of values have comma like this ('4,750.000') so the procedure are split the 4 number as separated field that's give an error

Comment: Oh its worked thank you so much really I appreciated it. Thnx alot again

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the quotes first?

Instead of :

```
line.Split(",")

line.Replace( """", "" ).Split(",")
```

NOTE: this isn't good if you actually have any data with quotes in it that where you want quotes written to your database

Comment: Nor is it good if the data contains quoted commas, where splitting would be wrong.

Comment: thank you very much for new splitting information really its useful but there are another error " The data was truncated while converting from one data type to another. [ Name of function(if known) =  ]"

Comment: Do any of the lines get in properly?  You can also find the value of sqlstr when it fails and try to manually run that against your database.  You want to check if your column values are in the correct order for what you are inserting in the database and if the columns in the database have the correct datatype (and are long enough if they are strings )

Comment: Actually I did but I dont know where is the problem if you check this two lines the first one is working but other not working

Comment: INSERT INTO pdt_item (item_code,loc,cost_price,run_spr,recd_dt,disp_flag,R_qty,s_qty,a_qty,stk_qty,O_qty) VALUES( '017245588' ,'I01','0.000','0.000','261013','N','0.000000','-2.000000','0.000000','-2.000000','0.000000' )
INSERT INTO pdt_item (item_code,loc,cost_price,run_spr,recd_dt,disp_flag,R_qty,s_qty,a_qty,stk_qty,O_qty) VALUES( '273012551' ,'I01','3','288.572','4','750.000','271013','N','250.000000','-164.000000','0.000000' )

Comment: Actually now the problem with the some of values have comma like this ('4,750.000') so the procedure are split the 4 number as separated field that's give an error

Answer (score -1):

Please use string as

```
"INSERT INTO pdt_item (item_code,loc,cost_price,run_spr,
recd_dt,disp_flag,R_qty, qty,a_qty,stk_qty,O_qty) 
VALUES( '" + fields(0) + "' ,'" + fields(1) + "','" + fields(2) + "','" + fields(3) +  
"','" + fields(4) + "','" + fields(5) + "','" + 
fields(6) + "','" + fields(7) + "','" + fields(8) + "','" + 
fields(9) + "','" + fields(10) + "' )";
```